# I configured FlDIGI to dislay letters before my PSK31 signal and then I forgot how I did it

Tags: digital-modes, fldigi

Several months ago, before I had a Transceiver that worked, I  configured FLDIGI to graphically display  the letters QC 13P in the waterfall as a preamble to my PSK31 transmission. I remember I was looking into Reed Solomon identifiers or Hellschreiber or something else to tell hams what mode I was using.  I would like to remove this from my PSK31 signal.  The only problem is I forgot how I did it and I can't find where I configured FLDIGI to work like this. Is it time to reinstall FLDIGI?  Will that configuration persist through the reinstall?  How do I undo what I did?

Comment: I figured it out.  I had video IDS check marked under Configure/IDS/Video

Comment: You could post that as an answer and click the checkmark

Comment: Yes, as @mike65535 said, you *should* post that as an answer, and then check it (mark it as accepted). Otherwise, the system will keep pushing this to the top. Plus, you'll get a few bonus points! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. In FLDIGI I had video IDS check marked under Configure/IDS/Video.
Here is the link to a video on YouTube that clearly explains what I needed to know.
https://youtu.be/nwkz0GNpA0I